How can I set the Sensitivity Label for Excel using Python on Linux?
I have been trying for a few days to programmatically add a Sensitivity Label to my Excel file using Python. I was able to do it using xlwings on Windows, but my RHEL9 container didn't work. I tried following the instructions in Setting sensitivity label for excel file using python. The xlwings version worked (on windows), but the workbook for the xslxwriter example, after using "set_custom_property" would no longer open with any content.
I looked at the unzipped excel xml files for "Before" and "After" adding manually or using xlwings and neither of them have the custom.xml file referenced in the xslxwriter example of the above link answer.
I'm looking for an example of how to do this using python only that'll work with Python 3.8+ on RHEL7 - RHEL9. Any suggestions?
The xlwings on Windows example from Setting sensitivity label for excel file using python worked. I tried just creating a LabelInfo.xml file in the docMetadata folder of the unzipped Excel file, but that didn't produce the expected results. Comparing the unzipped files, it looks like xlwings actually touches a bunch of files.

have you tried to treat the file as zip file and change the custom.xml like I suggest here:Add sensitivity label to Excel files stored inside a folder? I use it in linux devcontainer and it works fine.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
